# MySQL PHP fetch all the rows and loop 3 rows in 1 group

Tags: php, html, mysql

Let's say that i got a group with only 3 rows capable to fit in it. If there are 9 rows, there will be 3 groups. So, i fetch all the rows from mysql using this code :

```
$stmty = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE tableid = :tableid');
$stmty->bindValue(':tableid', $tableid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmty->execute();

while($sy = $stmty->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

So, when I got 9 rows, I want the rows to be divided by 3 and put in 1 group. so now the group will loop into 3 groups.

How can that be possible?

Thank you very much

```
The structures :

<div id="group1" >
<div class="rows1" ></div>
<div class="rows2" ></div>
<div class="rows3" ></div>
</div>

<div id="group2" >
<div class="rows4" ></div>
<div class="rows5" ></div>
<div class="rows6" ></div>
</div>

<div id="group3" >
<div class="rows7" ></div>
<div class="rows8" ></div>
<div class="rows9" ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php), like:

```
$result = $stmty->fetchAll();
$chunked = array_chunk($result, 3, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can work with array_chunk !

Comment: A bit of an explanartion would have been appropriate, otherwise, this would be more a comment than an answer.